# Providing a template of a good question for a user's first go

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We already do quite a bit to help encourage good questions from new users; a well formed help center, a generally supportive community, and a review system that targets new users to improve their posts as soon as possible.  I propose we do one more thing for the newest of users: templates.

The first time a user asks a question, we should consider putting a short template to give them guidance on what is usually a good question.  Something like this:

```
Thanks for asking your first question.  Here is where you might give a brief overview

A one sentence question should go here, separate of other text to be easily found


    Here is where you should put the specific code that is causing the issue.  
    Code is indented by 4 spaces
        Normal indenting applies

    Be sure to include all relevant code, but be concise!

This would be a good place for you to discuss what you think is wrong

And here, you should talk about what you've tried to solve the problem! <- Very important!

For more information, see the help center, or peruse meta-stackoverflow for specific questions.
```

Now, you may find yourself asking, with all that we do, why do more?  The answer is very simple.  A template is something that people must read or delete.  If someone deletes it straight away, without reading, then there's no helping them, and the question will likely be closed shortly.  However, if a new user reads it, they might be inspired to at least follow it *at least a little bit*, and that will help!

**A Brief Summary:**

- I propose the first question a user writes comes "prefilled" with a template
- This template contains the bare minimum information for making a decent question
- New users will be encouraged to avoid common errors
- This provides a unique benefit aside from the help center/meta because it cannot be avoided by a first-timer (unless they insta-delete it)

**Why this is unique from the first time quality page**

1. The first time quality page is much more formal than what I'm proposing, therefore users may be less receptive to it
2. The page goes away when it actually comes time to write the question, so unless the user had notes handy, they likely retain none of it.  Now, the user could navigate to the help center, but this is probably effort they aren't willing to put in.  However, the template, is there when the question is written, so it should be more helpful.  Of course, the user can delete this template never to see it return, but hopefully they'll delete it line by line

Comment: Wouldn't this be a bit insulting to us folks who already know how to compose a legible paragraph?

Comment: Well given that I'm suggesting it shows up only on the first question, I think most people are more thick skinned than that

Comment: I'd like to think that people would just look at some of the millions of examples of decent questions before asking, but there's plenty of evidence that they don't.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, I'd like to think that too, but unless it's in front of their face, many people _just don't care_.  So lets put it in their face just once!

Comment: You seem to think all good questions follow a set template. They don't. And forcing them can reduce the quality of actual good ones. By the way - do you know that we show an interstitial page explaining our quality requirement and that has a checkbox confirming reading it for our new users? Those that don't read it will not really care about such a template either.

Comment: @Oded, true, some questions won't follow this template, but that's why its just text, not set boxes on a form, users are free to change it.  And yes, I am aware of that, I'll update why this is unique from that, since its a little long for a comment

Comment: I don't see how this would improve anything significantly. It may help the one or two new users who actually read the instructions, but the majority will likely continue to just post terrible questions because they don't see their questions as terrible. The format of the question isn't really the issue, it's the content and subject of the question. *"Why doesn't my code work?"* questions typically have a short explanation, and code samples, which would fit your template nicely.

Comment: I came here to ask the same question, only for both questions and answers, and for a permanent fixture across all Stack Exchange sites for all users permanently. Some may not like it, but it's a change worth trying. Only I had in mind something more simple, such as just placing text like `Scenario`, `Problem`, `Code`, `Question`