# Good question templates

Tags: discussion, questions

Many new users come to Stack Overflow and ask questions before they know the requirements of the site. This creates many duplicate, off-topic, and unanswerable questions. Some people don't care, but for those who want to learn to ask better questions, I am making this a place that can be linked to for your guidance.

The answers below are templates of what a good question might include. There are many different kinds of questions and there isn't a one-size-fits-all kind of template. However, if you don't know where to start, choosing the template that best fits your type of question will help. **Click the *edit* button below the answer, and then copy the template text to your new question.** Add or remove from it according to your situation.

And if you haven't seen them already, read the following:

- [Stack Overflow Help Center: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

---

### Meta Comments

Unlike previous meta feature-requests asking for some sort of required template built into the system (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253152/providing-a-template-of-a-good-question-for-a-users-first-go), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254386/require-new-users-to-post-all-of-the-needed-parts-of-a-question-separately), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289030/should-so-provide-in-line-question-templates-to-promote-a-balance-between-length)), I am only soliciting answers right here that contain template samples which can be linked to from elsewhere. This is not a feature request to change the system in any way.

If I may, I'd like to request that meta discussion be kept to the comments, and the answers be reserved for actual question templates. If you have an issue with my idea and want to say more than a comment, I'd request that you make a new meta question and link to it in the comments.

Comment: _"If you have an issue with my idea and want to say more than a comment, I'd request that you make a new meta question and link to it in the comments."_ Yea, that won't work at all.That'd result in inception-like links with meta-discussions about meta-discussions.

Comment: @Cerbrus, hopefully not too inception-like, but I asked [Is it useful to ask for good question templates?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334199/is-it-useful-to-ask-for-good-question-templates). Please comment if I misrepresented your view.

Comment: When you talk about "template", you talk about something like the heading structure in this GitHub issue? https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/15411#issue-1533658062

Comment: @carloswm85, yes, maybe. I can't really remember what I was talking about back then.

Answer (score 13):

Anti-template (almost everything you need to avoid):

> Hi all and good evening. Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker and my dog ate my spellchecker. 
>   I'm a beginner in programming and I'm learning from tutorials found on internet. Today is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow. It's probably a silly question, I know there are many similar questions, but it's a different issue, it's not a duplicate. Yesterday I got a problem that my boss want me to repair asap. On our server, where we do not have any version control, I was reading the comment "DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING LINE UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES" left by the previous dev many years ago when suddenly my cat jumped on the keyboard and altered something then saved the document and closed the editor. I searched on Google but I couldn't find the previous dev. I tried everything and spent all night on this. It's driving me crazy. Now I need support from experts. Has anyone faced this issue before? Can anyone help me out there? What is the best way to fix the problem and solve the issue as quickly as possible? Any idea? You're my only hope, please, any kind of advice or recommendation or link is appreciated. Thanks in advance! If my question is not clear or if you need any details, you can contact me directly by email. You must upvote and share this question to 3 friends or your cloud account will be wiped out. [edit] Nevermind, I found the solution, you can delete the question now...

Comment: Not realistic: all of the words are spelled correctly and the punctuation is correct. For instance, it should be "Im a newb so plz dont minus me 2 much".

Comment: Not to **mention** a *lack of abuse* of `formatting`.

Comment: Adding comment template - "U only downvote cuz u dont kno answr! Go away l00sers!"

Comment: You cannot ask bad question even if you are determined to.

Comment: Ouch. You know this a perfect "bad question" template when your blood pressure rises while reading it, despite knowing it's supposed to be sarcastic.

Answer (score 8):

## All information you need to ask a proper question [is found here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Instead of linking to this meta question, link users to "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" in the help center. That topic there was written *specifically* for the users you're trying to help here. Don't separate the information.

If you feel that page is incomplete, submit a feature request to improve it.

Comment: It would be really, really helpful if there was on option in the review queues to automatically ping the user with the suggestion that their question does not meet these guidelines, with a link, asking them to read then re-ask.

Answer (score 4):

## Problem

I want to do ... in my application, but what I'm actually getting is....

Here is a screenshot that illustrates the problem:

## What I've tried

This is the most simplified version of my code that I've been able to get, which still produces the problem I described above.

```
// my code

...
```

Basically, what the code is doing is....

Changing ... does not work because it gives the following error:

> Some error

## My Research

[The documentation here] mentioned ... but did not provide a clear example of how that is done.

[This Stack Overflow question] describes a similar problem, but mine is different because....

## Question

So my basic question is, how do I...?

Comment: Calling out the major categories is great for expository purposes, but terrible for a template. I do *not* want to start seeing questions formatted like this. If all the parts are there, you don't need headings. As such, I'm leery about encouraging people to copy-paste from the raw markdown.

Comment: The problem with templates is that it makes users _lazy_. They'll just copy-paste their code dump into the template, then complain about downvotes because they "followed the template!".

Comment: @CodyGray, do you think that templates in general are not useful, or just this specific one with headings? Personally speaking, when I first started out, I think having something like this would have helped me include information that I often left out.

Comment: @Suragch: A checklist would've sufficed, then. That checklist already exists in "How to ask".

Comment: I'm not arguing against templates in general. I'm saying that including headings in a template that you're recommending people copy-paste is inevitably going to get those headings in people's questions. Which is something I don't want to see. *Ideally*, we might have a feature where the headings are visible during the construction phase as a guide, but not visible as part of the actual question. But then that starts getting into the feature requests you want to avoid, which are just specific instances of [the larger issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/).

Comment: @CodyGray, got it. I definitely support your [treatise to improve the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) as well as other related feature requests people have made. The idea of sharing templates just occurred to me as something I could do in the meantime.

Comment: If you think that's a treatise, you aren't very familiar with my Q&A :-)

Comment: @CodyGray, oops, I think I mixed up "treatise" and "entreaty". Anyway, I agree with your request for people to come up with concrete ways to improve the Ask a Question page.

Comment: @CodyGray Devils advocate: Are the headings so horrible? At the very least, you could clearly identify the parts of the question. Plus it would be a warning sign when some of them aren't filled out, no? Is it just the ugliness that you object to?