# Is it useful to ask for good question templates?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, help-center

I asked an unconventional meta question titled [Good question templates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334192/good-question-templates). I say unconventional because rather than the normal discussion based answers, I requested answers that were templates of what a good question might look like. My idea was that the best templates could be voted to the top.

One problem with that question, though, is that it assumes templates are useful and that having them to link to would be helpful. The following problems with that assumption were pointed out:

- People should be just going to the help center to know [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Having a separate place to link to separates the information.
- Templates make users lazy because they just copy and paste. When they get downvotes they will just complain that they followed the template.

I also know that there isn't any one template that can match all question types. However, I still tend to feel that having a set of templates to choose from would help new users, not as something to be rigidly followed but as a suggestion. Templates are more concrete examples of what the help center talks about.

What do other people think?

Comment: Hmm. Initial problematic things that spring to mind is that questions start to look alike too much and that people indeed copy/paste blindly. The problem with most new people is that they don't think enough about the content they put forth... this is basically feeding into that behavioural pattern. We instead need tools to break that pattern.

Comment: It would have been much better if you created a [meta-tag:faq]-like question instead of the way you formatted the one you linked.  I would have asked "What should I include in my question, and how should they be organized?", added an answer with the details I wanted to highlight, marked everything as a wiki and tagged it [meta-tag:faq-proposed].

Answer (score 5):

Templates aren't a solution.

Sure, they will probably help some users write better questions. They will also help other users write worse questions. Users could end up blindly copy-pasting the template, dumping code in there, using *"but I followed the template"* as an excuse as soon as the question's closed.

Imo, the information in the help center is plenty to write a good question.
If someone is of the opinion that it's not, he should submit a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to improve the info. Don't add it in a meta question, don't separate the information.

Comment: While I agree with this, it is also true that no one reads all of the information in the Help Center. The motivation is to figure out a way to increase the odds of new users asking a decent quality question. Throwing a giant wall of text at them and expecting them to help themselves is...not likely to result in success.

Comment: I agree, but why would a user that doesn't read the help center use the templates? Neither is a solution.