# Should I create a tag-specific question template and ask new users to refer to it for asking good question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users, minimal-reproducible-example

I work on the tag [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) most of the time on SO. Usually, the questions are about some query composing, like "how can I achieve behaviour xxx?". For us, people who are trying to help, usually several things are needed to create a minimal reproducible example.

For our case of [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb), usually below are needed:

1. sample json documents
2. expected output
3. current attempt of query/aggregation pipeline

One of the common tools we used to introduce above is [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/). It is useful for demonstrating behaviours so I think it could be a good idea to introduce the tool to new users in the question template too.

I understand that new users may not know the above elements are useful. So I am thinking of creating a MongoDB template question with the above elements and making a canned comment for new users to refer to that MongoDB template question.

I know that [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334192/good-question-templates) is asked before and we are suggested to direct new users to [help center how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But in my opinion, the how to ask page is quite general to all questions. Not saying that it is not applicable to our case of [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb), I just wish to provide an alternative that is more aligned to our specific case of [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) that could be more helpful to new users to learn what should be expected for asking [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) questions.

What are your thoughts about this? Should I create a specific MongoDB question template?

---

**Edit:**
Thanks @Rubén's answer for introducing me to the question [What's the best way to post a "How to ask a good question?" article for a specific subject?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417282/whats-the-best-way-to-post-a-how-to-ask-a-good-question-article-for-a-specif). I am looking for something like the SQL section of that question, and in the form of actual SO question with some description inside to indicate it is a template.

---

**Edit 2023-02-26:**
I created [this self Q&A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573599/how-do-i-ask-a-good-question-about-mongodb) and create a community wiki answer to do the above. However, seemingly it is not well-received. Any other suggestions for the correct place or correct way to do that?

Comment: I wonder if MongoDB ever has an active chat room since your question appears to be quite specific for this tag?

Comment: Can you outline what you mean by "template"? Are you referring to the existing content template generation tool like the ones StackApps has enabled (but [declined for Stack Overflow here](/a/365362/15497888))? Or some supplemental documentation elsewhere?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels None that I am aware of. Do you know how I can check?

Comment: @HenryEcker Editted the question to include some new insights from Rubén's answer

Comment: Perhaps it could be combined with making the corresponding tag wiki be more visible. Perhaps even let content in a particular format in the tag wiki trigger such templates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several things that should be developed more, I'm not sure if this is something that should be done on the question body of this question or on the previous questions about templates like

- [Good question templates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334192/1595451) from 2016
- [Is it useful to ask for good question templates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334199/1595451) from 2016
- [What can we put in a question template to help people ask better questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357951/1595451), by someone from the Staff, from 2017
- [Ask a question template v1 experiment results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/1595451), by someone from the Staff, from 2018

Some ideas bout things to be developed:

- How new users will learn about the template

  - Should new users learn about the template in the tag wiki, Meta or from a faq / reference like question on the main site?
- When new users will learn about the template

  - Should users learn about template while searching the site prior posting a question?
- How the template will work with [ask-question-wizard](/questions/tagged/ask-question-wizard) and [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground)

  - Should the tags having a template should also have a [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground) canned comment?
  - Should there be a tag-tip / tag-warning suggesting the user to use a template?

#### Related

- [What's the best way to post a "How to ask a good question?" article for a specific subject?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417282/1595451)

[mcve](/questions/tagged/mcve), specific tag

- [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405791/1595451)

[mcve](/questions/tagged/mcve)

- [What more can be done to prevent questions with just external links/images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397902/1595451)

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [mcve](/questions/tagged/mcve)

- [Could we add a tag-specific MRE page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366424/1595451)

---

#### Possible inspiration sources

[r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq)

- [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1595451)

Comment: I would say I am hoping for something similar to the SQL section in your link of [What's the best way to post a "How to ask a good question?" article for a specific subject?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417282/whats-the-best-way-to-post-a-how-to-ask-a-good-question-article-for-a-specif). For my current thought, I am thinking about asking a SO question myself with [tag:mongodb] and put some description inside to indicate that is the template.

Comment: @ray Added a link to a feature request and to a "`r-faq`"

Comment: Many tags with associated playgrounds like the typescript playground can absolutely benefit from this.